# ffmpeg error when trying to combine multiple splitted audio clips

Tags: python-3.x, ffmpeg, subprocess

I'm trying to use `ffmpeg` and `subprocess` in python to split a few clips from the given audio and combine them.

The command works in my terminal :

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 \
-af "aselect='between(t, 4, 6)+between(t, 70, 80)', asetpts=N/SR/TB" out.wav
```

However when I try to replicate the same using `subprocess`, I get the following error:

```
[NULL @ 0x7fc5f600a600] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'between(t, 4, 6)+between(t, 70, 80)'
between(t, 4, 6)+between(t, 70, 80): Invalid argument
CompletedProcess(args=['ffmpeg', '-i', 'input.mp3', '-af', '"aselect=\'', 'between(t, 4, 6)+between(t, 70, 80)', "', ", 'asetpts = N/SR/TB"', 'out.wav'], returncode=1)
```

Code :

```py
import subprocess
input_url = 'input.mp3'
output_file = 'out.wav'
clips = [[4, 6], [70,80]] #start, end
clip_parts = []
for clip_stamps in clips:
    start, end = clip_stamps
    temp_part = "between" + "(" + "t, " + str(start) + ", " + str(end) + ")"
    if clip_parts is None:
        clip_parts = [temp_part]
    else:
        clip_parts.append(temp_part)
subprocess.run([
    "ffmpeg",
    "-i",
    input_url,
    "-af",
    "\"aselect='",
    '+'.join(clip_parts),
    "', ",
    "asetpts = N/SR/TB\"",
    output_file
])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues regarding `subprocess.run`:

- `subprocess.run` automatically adds `"` character around arguments with special characters.
  For example, `"\"aselect='` becomes `"\"aselect='"`, so there is extra `"\"`
- Every element in the list is a command line argument.
  `"aselect='between(t, 4, 6)+between(t, 70, 80)', asetpts=N/SR/TB"` is a single argument, and should not be split to into [`"\"aselect='"`, `'+'.join(clip_parts)`, `"', "`, `"asetpts = N/SR/TB\""`].

For inspecting the actual command line, you may add `-report` argument, and check the log file created by FFmpeg.

---

Your command (with `-report`) is translated to:
`ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -af "\"aselect='" "between(t, 4, 6)+between(t, 70, 80)" "', " "asetpts = N/SR/TB\"" out.wav -report`

As you can see there are extra `"` characters.

---

Corrected code:

```
import subprocess

input_url = 'input.mp3'
output_file = 'out.wav'
clips = [[4, 6], [70,80]] #start, end
clip_parts = []

for clip_stamps in clips:
    start, end = clip_stamps
    temp_part = "between" + "(" + "t, " + str(start) + ", " + str(end) + ")"
    if clip_parts is None:
        clip_parts = [temp_part]
    else:
        clip_parts.append(temp_part)

subprocess.run([
    "ffmpeg",
    "-i",
    input_url,
    "-af",
    "aselect='" + '+'.join(clip_parts) + "', " + "asetpts=N/SR/TB",
    output_file
])
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks mate! Also appreciate you highlighting those issues, wasn't aware of it :)